# xlsx package and Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xls

I'm using `xlsx` to read from my Excel files (actually OpenOffice, saved as .xls) with the read.xlsx function.

It's working perfectly fine in `.R` scripts, and it runs perfectly fine in `.Rmd` code chunks. But then when I try to make a pdf/html/whatever using `knitr`, I get:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "read.xlsx"
>   Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Help? How can it not find a function it has already used in the same `.Rmd` file?

Comment: Please provide a working example. One possibility is that with you compile your Rmd file, you must include `library(openxlsx)` (or similar library) in a code chunk prior to calling `read.xlsx`. If you have the library open in your current R session, it doesn't count. The compilation process opens a fresh R session.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem.